# How to get my Django REST api to interact with Angular front-end be hosted over an nginx server

Tags: django, angular, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am trying to launch my web app with Django, Angular, and Nginx.  During the development phase I made services within Angular that send requests to 127.0.0.1:8000 I was able to get my Angular project to display over my domain name. However, when I try to log into my app over another network it won't work. Is this because I am pointing at 127.0.0.1:8000? Do I need to configure a web server gateway or api gateway for Django? Do I need to point the services in Angular to a different address? Or did I configure something wrong within Nginx? if anyone can help me I would greatly appreciate it.

```
upstream django_server{
        server 127.0.0.1:8000;
    }
    
    
    server{
    
        listen 80;
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name example.com www.example.com;
        ssl_certificate C:/Certbot/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key C:/Certbot/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
        root /nginx_test/www1/example.com;
        index index.html;
        location = /favicon.ico {
            return 204;
            access_log     off;
            log_not_found  off;
        }
         location /api-token/ {
          proxy_pass http://django_server/api-token/;

          proxy_http_version 1.1;

          proxy_set_header Host               $host;
          proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
            }
        
    
    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason is in your Angular service configuration. Instead of 127.0.0.1 try to change it to your REST API server IP address.

As I understand in your case when you open your app in the browser you load all static files into your pc/laptop browser. Because of that every time when you trigger frontend service you try to get response from your laptop/pc instead of your backed server.